# How can I specify the type of a row in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-hinting

If I have a function that's returning a DataFrame, and I know that each row will look like a certain `Dto` class, what package should I be using to be able to specify that the columns of the DataFrame match the attributes of the `Dto` class?

e.g.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json
from pandas import DataFrame

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Dto:
  id: int
  name: str

def get_dataframe() -> DataFrame[Dto]:
  dto: Dto = Dto(id=1, name='alice')
  json: Dict[str, int|str] = dto.to_dict()
  return DataFrame([json])

def use_dataframe(df: DataFrame[Dto]):
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # row has type Dto here
    print(f'the id of {row.name} is {row.id}')
```

in the above example, i want those typehints so that i know what the columns are in the rows i'm getting.  I want to be able to assume that each `row` will have `name` and `id` attributes, and get warnings if i try and send a dataframe with different columns into that `use_dataframe` function.

Answer (score 0):

one option looks like [`dataenforce`](https://pypi.org/project/dataenforce/), and the solution above would look like this:

```
from dataenforce import Dataset

DtoDataframe = Dataset["id":int, "name":str]

def get_dataframe() -> DtoDataframe:
  dto: Dto = Dto(id=1, name='alice')
  json: Dict[str, int|str] = dto.to_dict()
  return DataFrame([json])

def use_dataframe(df: DtoDataframe):
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # row has type Dto here
    print(f'the id of {row["name"]} is {row["id"]')
```

not ideal, since i have to use a string to specify the columns in `use_dataframe`.  ideally, i'd be able to type `row.` and have `row.name` and `row.id` come up in autocomplete.